# spam фильтр thunderbird на уже пришедшие письма

Tags: email, thunderbird

имеем почтовый ящик на 5к+ писем за 2 месяца, около 30% - спам. До этого спам фильтра вообще не было. Цель отсортировать уже принятые письма на спам/не спам. Реально такое организовать?

Comment: `Инструменты > Фильтры сообщений.` В этом списке найдите фильтр "Spam", ниже, в списке папок, выберите нужную и нажмите на кнопку "Запустить".

Comment: этот список пуст

Comment: разобрался, создаем новый, выбираем "метка спама" и запускаем.

Comment: отлично. у меня, просто, эти фильтры создаются сами.